# Passenger standalone with custom ruby path

Tags: ruby, passenger

I need to use passenger standalone with custom ruby installed in my home directory. However when I do `passenger start` it uses system ruby. How could I configure it to use the ruby version I want to use?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to reproduce the issue, as my setup is different...

...did you try adding the ruby version to the end of the gem file (heroku and rvm both read the gem file to automatically set the correct ruby version for execution).

try adding this line at the end of `Gemfile`:

`ruby "2.1.2"`

replace the version number for whatever your application requires.

Please keep me posted, I will try installing the Passenger as a stand alone later tonight.

(would have left this as a comment, but I have limited access to the features on this site).

Comment: I have some issues with RVM. Finally I use:
`/path/to/rvm do 2.0.0 do passenger start` and it works. Thanks for your help.